# Move the scroll of a flex item on a child element

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I use flexbox to set my layout.
I have a codepen.io to simplify my problem : [http://codepen.io/...](http://codepen.io/kapik/pen/CalAs)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">...</div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-1">...</div>
        <div id="content-2">      
            <div id="content-2-wrapper">
                <div id="content-2-header">
                  My content header
                </div>
                <div id="content-2-content">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>  

</div>
```

*I can't post all my code...*

As you can see there is the content #content-2.
In this content, there is a title and its content.

I would like :

- no scroll on #content-2
- scroll on #content-2-content

I try but no solution.
Maybe, I have to add a new flex container (#content-2-wrapper) but without success

Thanks in advance for your help !
(I'm still looking)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-y: scroll` from `#content-2` and instead add `overflow: hidden`. Next, define a fixed height for the `#content-2-content` div and set its `overflow` to `scroll` like this:

```
#content-2-content {
    height: 290px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here's the link to **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AyaKt)**.

Comment: I can't know the `height` of this element !
`#content-1` and `#content-2` have variable `height`